# how to make all tracked files back to untracked so the .gitignore can work?

Tags: git

i have one question:

i commit all files to remote repo with git.

`git commit -m "All Files with cache and session Directories"`

`git push origin master`

After this i try to configure .gitignore with some directories an files

```
nano .gitignore
```

Now i want to make some changes on files. Or i visit my local WebProject again.

After this the system create a lot of cache files. The directories are defined/stand in .gitignore.

The Problem is that git doesnt care about the .gitignore, becouse all files are tracked.

I see all files which are created or chnaged with `git status`

I try:

```
git rm --cached files
```

The result ist that the files on local are untracked now, .gitignore is working !!BUT!! this files are deleted after commit and push on my remote repo.

**Now, how can i untracked files?**

So the next one who would clone this repo he would miss a lot of directories.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by *deleted* - are they deleted on your local machine? If you mean deleted in your repository: then, yes. That is what gitignore does.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have errors your .gitignore rules? Use the command `git check-ignore` on a cache file to check if the set of .gitignore rules is not empty.

Answer (score 1):

> So the next one who would clone this repo he would miss a lot of directories.

Don't worry, the directories will only get deleted if one switches from a commit that contains them (i.e. *before* you did `git rm --cached`) to one that doesn't contain them (i.e. *after* you did `git rm --cached`). That is what happened to on the server. If somebody clones the repo now, it will not delete those directories on their local machine. It will only do so if they checkout one of those older commits, then checkout a newer one.

All that being said, since these directories are generated anyway, it shouldn't be the end of the world if they are deleted.

Answer (score 0):

> `git rm --cached files`
>   The result is that the files on local are untracked now, .gitignore is working !!BUT!! this files are deleted after commit and push on my remote repo.

Yep, you have deleted your file form the repository. This is exactly what the `git rm --cached files` do

---

You can use the `assume-unchanged` flag  so you dont need to modify your `.gitignore` file
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index

#### --[no-]assume-unchanged

> When this flag is specified, the object names recorded for the paths are not updated.
>
> Instead, this option sets/unsets the "assume unchanged" bit for the paths.
>
> When the "assume unchanged" bit is on, the user promises not to change the file and allows Git to assume that the working tree file matches what is recorded in the index. If you want to change the working tree file, you need to unset the bit to tell Git. This is sometimes helpful when working with a big project on a filesystem that has very slow lstat(2) system call (e.g. cifs).
>
> Git will fail (gracefully) in case it needs to modify this file in the index e.g. when merging in a commit; thus, in case the assumed-untracked file is changed upstream, you will need to handle the situation manually.

[image]